# Server is losing its static IP address

Tags: dhcp, ip-address

I have a Ubuntu server with the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address a.b.c.d
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway a.b.c.254
```

When I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, it works as expected.

In the same LAN, I have a DHCP server. From time to time, Ubuntu server unexpectedly loses its static IP, and gets one from a DHCP for an unknown reason to me.

Running `/etc/init.d/networking restart` corrects the address to the desired one.

What is the cause of this issue, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happend to me sometime, solved by uninstalling dhcp client. No use on server anyway.

Comment: Oh I dunno.  I use dhclient on servers sometimes.  It's all fine if the DHCP server is handing out static leases.

Comment: Perfectly suitable for me... No need for dhcpclient

Answer (score 2):

Something invoked `dhclient` without specifying an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out that ' cloud-init ' was installed on my system. It had configuration files in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ for eth0 which defined a DHCP setup, while I had static config in /etc/network/interfaces

I removed the cloud-init package and manually removed the files in /etc/network/interfaces.d/